# How do I convert a list of numbers to a string in k?

Tags: kdb

Given:

```
a:10 20 30
```

How do I get:

```
"102030"
```

?

I can only find:

```
`c$a
```

But that's definitely not it.

In q there is:

```
string 42
```

which returns:

```
"42"
```

but I cannot find the equivalent in k.

Comment: What is the driving force for working in k?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `K` required statement will look like:

```
k) ,/$a
```

Where `,/` is `raze` equivalent and `$` is `string` function equivalent.

There are not many good `K` tutorials. But I found last one created by [Shakti](https://shakti.com/tutorial/) is quite complete, though it may be not fully compatible with Kx's `K`